# How to undo "git pull origin" command of git on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, rollback

How to undo `git pull origin` command?. i connected to the amazon server `ec2-instance` using `ssh` and `pemfile`. and i navigated to the `project` directory on this `server`. And `ran` the "git pull origin". i want to undo this operation on this `aws instance`. how can i do this. this is a `ruby on rails` application

Answer (score 0):

The answers mentioning only `git reset --hard` are not correct. Once you have done a `pull`, your `HEAD` has moved forward to the new point you updated to. The implied ref for `git reset` is `HEAD`, so that command will just reset you to... the place you already are.

JonasJR was closer when mentioning reflog. The reflog is a local history of every action you take. If you just performed a pull, it might look something like this.

```
$ git reflog
6dd1a7b93 HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
e45d35313 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from feature to master
... more ...
```

Here I have the last two actions I have taken. A pull, and just prior to that I used checkout to change branches.

To go back to the state before the pull, I can use its ref (`HEAD@{1}`).

```
git reset --hard 'HEAD@{1}'
```

Now if I look in the reflog, it will show I reset to that prior state. The reset itself has become part of the history, so you can also use `reflog` to undo a mistaken undo, if you need to.

```
$ git reflog
e45d35313 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
6dd1a7b93 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
e45d35313 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from feature to master
```

As you can see, we've now gone away from `6dd1a7b93` and gone back to the previous state, `e45d35313` (which is both `HEAD@{2}` and `HEAD@{0}` at this point).

Note that the reflog is local to this copy of the repo. If you checkout a copy somewhere else, it has its own completely independent reflog. This is not shared with other people on your project, etc.

The usual disclaimer with `reset --hard` apply here. If you have uncommitted changes at the moment, this command will wipe them out. In that case, use `git stash` to set them aside while you do your reset.

Answer (score -1):

You want to undo the merge. Run this command:

```
git reset --hard
```

You can also reset to a specific state by running the same command and adding the SHA1 of the decired state. Run:

```
git reflog
```

to find out more about it!

Comment: I want to "rollback" only the last "git pull origin" command. will the above solution can do the last pull rollback?

Comment: First run the `git reflog` and take the SHA1 from the commit you wish to reset to, then run `git reset --hard [SHA1 of the commit]`

Comment: @JonasJR As written this answer is not correct. Just doing a reset like this will reset to `HEAD`, and that is where the OP already is. You're on the right track with reflog, but the initial reset command will not undo what the OP asked about.